# Subset of colormap Matplotlib in RGB to html

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I am interested in using the `cmap('hot')` from Matplotlib as a Bokeh palette.

First, I choose the Matplotlib colormap subset given by

```
from Matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors_mpl = [i for i in plt.get_cmap('hot')(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, 6))]
```

Initially, given an set of RGB colors, I could convert to html by using the built-in function `to_hex`.

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
colors_html = [to_hex(rgb/255) for rgb in colors_mpl]]
```

However, the output I get is not the expected as I get very small differences between colors:

```
['#000000', '#010000', '#010000', '#010100', '#010100', '#010101']
```

The expected output is

```
['#2a0000', '#a30000', '#ff1d00', '#ff9800', '#ffff1b', '#ffffd0']
```

Any ideas of how to convert the colormap to html properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't divide by `255`, `colors_mplt` are already in scale `0-1`:

```
colors_html = [to_hex(rgb) for rgb in colors_mpl]
# out
# ['#2a0000', '#a30000', '#ff1d00', '#ff9800', '#ffff1b', '#ffffd0']
```